# Python GTK3 add Image to Widget

Tags: python, image, gtk3, glade

I have the following snippet:

```
def updateImages(self):
  filename = '.\scripts\file.png'
  self.image = Gtk.Image()
  image.set_from_file(filename)
  # i need a line here to put the file object in a widget
  image.show()
```

when I load the GUI built using Glade, i have a specific area for the picture, see below.
How do I connect `image` to that area (`picturearea`)?

```
  self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
  self.picturearea = self.builder.get_object('picturearea')
```

---

Updated Example:

```
class Picture(Gtk.Window):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
    self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
    self.builder.add_objects_from_file('layout.glade', ('window1',''))
    #self.builder.connect_signals(Signals())
    thewindow = self.builder.get_object('window1')

    self.picturearea = self.builder.get_object('imagefield')

    filechooserbutton = self.builder.get_object('button2')
    button = self.builder.get_object('button1')
    button.connect("clicked", self.on_load_image_clicked)
    filechooserbutton.connect("clicked", self.on_chooser_clicked)
    self.text_entry = self.builder.get_object('entry1')
    thewindow.set_title("Show an image")
    thewindow.show_all() 

def on_load_image_clicked(self, button):
    #currentpicture = self.picturearea.get_child()
    #self.picturearea.remove(currentpicture)

    image = Gtk.Image()
    path = self.text_entry.get_text()
    try:
        image.set_from_file(path)
        self.picturearea.add(image)
        image.show()
        self.picturearea.show_all()
    except:
        pass

def on_chooser_clicked(self, button):
    dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please select an image file", self, Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN, ( Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL, Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))
    response = dialog.run()
    if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
        print "Response was OK"
        text = dialog.get_filename()
        self.text_entry.set_text(text)

    dialog.destroy()


app = Picture()
app.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
Gtk.main()
```

However, the image still doesn't show (using an imagefield for  in glade)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is your `picturearea` object, but normally it could be a Box or a DrawingArea. Also you seem to be creating an image, but you are not adding the image to any widget.

The following example works by using a box:

```
#/usr/bin/env python3

from gi.repository import Gtk

def update_image(widged, data=None):

    # remove the previous image
    for child in image_area.get_children():
        image_area.remove(child)

    ## add a new image
    image = Gtk.Image()
    image.set_from_file('./test.png')
    image_area.add(image)
    image_area.show_all()


window = Gtk.Window()
box = Gtk.VBox()
image_area = Gtk.Box()


button=Gtk.Button(label="click me to set the image")
button.connect('clicked', update_image)


box.add(button)
box.add(image_area)
window.add(box)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

(Of course that you can define the Box in glade..)

Comment: `picturearea` is a scrollable window in Glade, but I could change it to a Box or DrawingArea. My questions is this; given that I have retrieved the widget programatically, i.e. using `Gtk.Builder()` and `get_object('name')`, how do I set it's value/data to a picture file? Your answer seems to indicate that `widget.add` and `widget.remove` does the trick?

Regards

Comment: @enrm What you need to do is to create the container in glade, and in your python code create the image and add it to the container. If you want to have a scrollable area maybe (I'm not 100% sure) you need to create a box inside the scrollable area, and then add the picture inside the box as I posted in my example!

Comment: @enrm by the way, you should always post minimal examples when asking here so we can provide a solution. If you post only a part of a big code we can not do much. You should be able of modifying my example to make it work with glade!

Comment: Actually, I've narrowed it down to the problem being the path. if I do `set_from_file('./file.jpg')` it works, but if i use the absolute path `C:\users\enrm\file.jpg` it doesn't work.. Any idea how to make the absolute path work with `set_from_file` ? 

Regards